# How can I update an instance variable with each ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, instance-variables

I have a long block of comments on a view of model `Page`. Instead of showing all the comments on page load, I'm trying to create a "view more" button that shows the next ten comments. The button sends an ajax request to the controller, which then renders this block using jquery:

**_view_more.html.erb**

```
<% comments.each_with_index do |comment, index|%>
  <% if (( index > @start_number) && (index < @end_number) ) %>
  <%= comment.text %>
<% end %>
```

---

Let's say I always want to show the next 10 comments. I would just set `@start_number = @start_number + 10` and `@end_number = @end_number + 10`
in the controller, but instance variables get reset, so `@start_number` would be nil. How can I set a variable that increases by 10 upon every ajax request?

**"view more" button**

```
<%= link_to "view more", view_more_page_path, remote: true %>
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```
def view_more
  @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_path }
    format.js
  end
end
```

**view_more**

```
$("#comments-body").append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'view_more') %>");
```

Comment: I understand that this doesn't answer your question, but are you sure you don't want to just keep track on the client side and send the start and (if necessary) end indexes with the ajax requests?

Comment: @JMM I hadn't considered it. How could I do that?

Answer (score 4):

I will use `haml` and `coffee-script`

When rendering `comments` you put an `html5` `data attribute` with the `id` of the `comment`:

```
#view where to render comments
%div#comments-wrapper{:"data-pageid" => @page.id}
  =render @comments
=link_to "View more", "#", id: "view-more-link"
```

The comment partial

```
#comments/_comment.html.haml
%p.single-comment{:"data-commentid" => comment.id}
  =comment.body
```

application.coffee

```
$ ->
  $("#view-more-link").on 'click', ->
    last_comment_id = $("#comments-wrapper .single-comment").last().data('commentid')
    page_id = $("#comments-wrapper").data("pageid")
    $.ajax
      url: "/comments/view_more"
      dataType: "script"
      data:
        last_comment_id: last_comment_id
        page_id: page_id
```

comments_controller

```
def view_more
  @page = Page.find(params[:pageid])
  if params[:last_comment_id]
    @comments = @page.comments.where("comments.id > ?", params[:last_comment_id]).limit(10)
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

comments/view_more.js.erb

```
$("#comments-wrapper").append("<%= escape_javascript(render @comments) %>");
```

Note: I don't how your routes were set up so I put the `page.id` as a data-attribute as well

Answer (score 4):

I would use already implemented pagination gems [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) or [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate). I'll create this example using will_paginate.

First of all, it's important to say that your approach is incorrect, because **it loads all comments** every `view_more` request. If you want to show 10 comments, makes sense select only they from database, right? The pagination gem will do it for you!

Let's to the code:

**"view more" button**

```
<%= link_to "view more", view_more_page_path, remote: true, id: 'view-more-btn' %>
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```
def view_more
  @comments = Page.find(params[:id]).comments.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_path }
    format.js
  end
end
```

**_view_more.html.erb**

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.text %>
<% end %>
```

**view_more.js.erb**

```
$("#comments-wrapper").append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'view_more') %>");
# We need to update the 'view more' link with the next page number
$('#view-more-btn').attr('href', '<%= view_more_page_path((params[:page] || 0) + 1) %>')
```

Comment: Is that really enough code? It seems too simple to actually work.

Comment: For example, how can I select how many records are returned per page?

Comment: @JoeMorano, You will need to install de will_paginate gem

Comment: Nothing happens when I press the button. Do I need to to require a file somewhere for the gem to work?

Comment: No @JoeMorano. The AJAX request is made when you press the button?

Answer (score 0):

is it not good to update an hidden variable before making ajax call with the count..?

```
var currentVal = parseInt($("[type=hidden]").val());
$("[type=hidden]").val( currentVal + 1 );
```

add the hidden field right at the begining of the comments section with default value as "0"

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenId" id="hiddenId" value="0">
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick and dirty approach, you could save start_number and end_number inside a [cookie](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html).

But keeping track of what needs to be rendered next on client side would be a right thing to do.